# Texture based image segmentation

Tags: image, opencv, image-recognition, image-segmentation

I've got photo of room with carpet on the floor. I've got texture sample of carpet. I want to detect carpet borders on photo.

Could you please describe how to perform texture based Image segmentation using opencv?

Comment: It would be possible to write a book in answer to your question. Could you narrow it down somewhat? What have you tried? E.g Gabor filter bank? Google "texture segmentation" is a good place to start.

Comment: currently I've implemented algorithm that calculates average color of texture and perform segmentation based on color. This shows good results in case texture has low degree of variety. Now I am going to make some hysto analyse with pixel probability... I am new to Opencv so I am not sure that I am on right way...

Comment: You might want to look in to [histogram backprojection](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/back_projection/back_projection.html#back-projection). It's not an advanced approach, but it might work well enough.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I am currently looking for that

Answer (score 0):

You can apply an edge detecting filter, like canny to extract the edges as a feature. then you can apply a similarity function between the distance-points of the carpet in your template and try to find a scaling parameter for the lines you have extracted in your edge detection phase.

You can also use some deep learning algorithms which are more complicated.